# Redirecting the authenticated user to a different page other than the signup page

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following route that brings me to a signup/signin page when typing localhost/TestSite/

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->name('home');
```

This works fine if the user is not logged in, but I want the user to be directed to another page (e.g. Dashboard) in case he was logged in after typing the same URL as above. An example would be after closing the browser by mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a `guest` middleware (`RedirectIfAuthenticated`) on that route. It will only allow non authenticated users to reach it and will redirect authenticated users away from it. You can define where they go to in that middleware itself.

```
Route::get('/', ...)->name('home')->middleware('guest');

// app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php

public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        // where ever you want the authenticated user to be redirected to
        return redirect('/dashboard');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: I'm trying the above but I'm not able to properly create the route. Can you please provide the full route ?

Comment: it is the exact route you have, just add `->middleware('guest')` to the end of the definition

Comment: localhost redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: I'm on laravel 5.2 , and the authetication file you mentioned is named authenticate.php

Comment: it is not `Authenticate.php`, it is `RedirectIfAuthenticated.php`. Check `app/Http/Kernel.php` for `routeMiddleware` named `guest`

Answer (score 1):

go to the middleware folder, open RedirectIfAuthenticated and change the redirect to your dashboard, e.g

```
class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/dashboard');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

then visit the Auth folder, LoginController, and change the value of the redirect also like so

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```